# Converting char[] to Int[]

Tags: c

I have an char array like this:

```
char res[80]="00001111001010100100001010101100000010011100001000110010000101000100001010010001"
```

want to change into

```
int res[80]=00001111001010100100001010101100000010011100001000110010000101000100001010010001
```

have done something like this:

```
char res[80]="00001111001010100100001010101100000010011100001000110010000101000100001010010001";
int resInt[80];
for (int i = 0; i<80; i++) {
    resInt [i] = res[i];
    printf("%d",resInt[i]);
}
```

the result is like this:

```
4848484849494949484849484948494848494848484849484948494849494848484848484948484949494848484849484848494948484948484848494849484848494848484849484948484948484849
```

can anyone help me??
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ASCII '0' is actually 48 in scalar form, so subtract it out:

```
resInt[i] = res[i] - '0';
```

Comment: @BakhtiarYusuf , Instead of posting "Thanks!" , Accept the answer since it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Character literals are of type int in C. You can convert a char type simply by assigning to an int. However, the resulting int values will be ASCII values. So you need to subtract out the ASCII value of char '0' to get the actual value.

resInt[i] = res[i] - '0';